# The maximum length of a message that can be hashed with WHIRLPOOL

Tags: hash, passwords, cryptography, whirlpool

I'm just wondering what is the maximum length. I read from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whirlpool_%28cryptography%29) that it takes a message of any length less than 2^256 bits. Does that mean 2 to the power of 256? Also, would it be more secure to hash a password multiple times? Example:

```
WHIRLPOOL(WHIRLPOOL(WHIRLPOOL(WHIRLPOOL("passw0rd"))))
```

Or does that increase the risk of collisions?

Comment: Please read this whole page before going further: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#ineffective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this does mean 2^256 bits. Of course, as there are 2^3 bits in a byte, you will thus have a maximum space of 2^253 bytes. Nothing to worry about.

Yes, it is better to hash multiple times. No, you don't have to worry about "cycles" (much). Many pseudo random number generators are using hashes the same way. Hash algorithms should not loose too much information and should not have a short cycle time.

---

Passwords hashes are should however be calculated using password based key derivation functions. The "key" is then stored. PBKDF's may use hashes (e.g. PBKDF2) or keyed block ciphers (bcrypt). Most KDF's are using message authentication codes (HMAC or MAC) instead of directly using the underlying hash algorithm or block cipher.

Input to PBKDF's is a salt and iteration count. The iteration count is used to make it harder for an attacker to brute force the system by trying out all kinds of passwords. It's basically the same as what you did above with WHIRLPOOL. Only the iteration count is normally somewhere between 1 and 10 *thousand*. More data is normally mixed in as well in each iteration.

More importantly, the (password specific) salt is used to make sure that duplicate passwords cannot be detected and to avoid attacks using rainbow tables. Normally the salt is about 64 to 128 bits. The salt and iteration count should be stored with the "hash".

---

Finally, it is probably better to use a NIST vetted hash algorithm such as SHA-512 instead of WHIRLPOOL.

Comment: Whirlpool is still in the ISO/IEC 10118 list of "approved" hash functions...
https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:10118:-3:ed-4:v1:en
13 Dedicated Hash-Function 7 (WHIRLPOOL)